# Is there a “recovery window” (such as there is a protein “feeding window”?

Tags: protein, recovery

Bob trains really hard and makes several PBs but doesn’t fuel his recovery within the following (approximately) 6 hours with adequate protein.

It seems that the common wisdom is that he largely loses out on the potentially resultant gains from this session, even if he eats tons of protein 10 or 20 hours after his training.

Charles has a really heavy day of training but his sleep that night is disturbed by some Jack hammers working outside his house early in the morning, cutting it short at 5 hours. However Charles makes up the missing sleep later the following afternoon or with an extra early bedtime the following night.

What happens to Charles’s gains?